# Bilingual Linux GUI

Tags: gui, language-support

I would like to make my Linux computer bilingual. 
Is it possible for two languages to be displayed at the same time as the languages of the GUI?
If possible - How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: In my experience using Ubuntu in French, half the GUI is still in English anyway ;-)

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to do this. I have to imagine that if it were a feature, it would have taken an immense amount of time for the developers to add, and most people wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translation libraries are not developed this way. It will just complicate things further to have a UI with simultaneous multilingual messages, because some formatting and features only make sense in a certain language.